# PHP DATABASE - USERS

Tags: php, mysql

How could one allow a user to have privileges to remove/add items from the products database?

```
- users -
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| name | surname | country | address | email | username | password |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
- products -
------------------------------
| id | item | prize | number |
------------------------------
```

- id:       product id;
- item:     product name;
- prize:    product price;
- number:   product availability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest thing that you can try, you can add a `user_type` column in your `users` table and use its value in your php code. For example:

```
<?php
//select data from users table first

if ($row['user_type'] == "Admin"){
     //put here the functions and/or objects that you want to be done under Admin control
} else{
     //put here the functions and/or objects that you want to be done under other users
}

?>
```

There are many ways on how to do it. You just need to think of one.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way out (might cause you pain later)**

Add `user_type` to your `users` table. Then only let that specific user type to use the remove/add functions.

**More cumbersome (but you'll thank yourself later when you want to add new access levels)**

Look into using a proper ACL model, where you use multiple tables and a `user_id` to handle access. [Here's some info on the topic](http://www.developer.com/lang/php/creating-a-custom-acl-in-php.html). There are also some open source stuff out there, e.g. [Tackle](http://tackle-tiny-acl-authentication-for-php.soft112.com/).